# M1 MacBook Apple ML compute Tensorflow2.4 compatibility issue with Numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am running the new apple native tensorflow package 2.4, and ran into a problem I did not have before. This jupyter notebook code works in old intel based environment where an older tensorflow version was used. But with M1 apple MLcomputer TensorFlow2.4 it is not compatible
with Numpy 1.20 or 1.18(I downgraded numpy to try). The error log:

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (lstm_1/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-20-73358e637fe3> in <module>
          4 model = Sequential()
          5 model.add(Embedding(vocab_size+1, W2V_SIZE, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, trainable=False))
    ----> 6 model.add(LSTM(500, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
          7 model.add(Dense(units = 10000, kernel_initializer = 'glorot_uniform', activation = 'relu'))
          8 model.add(Dropout(0.35))
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
        515     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
        516     try:
    --> 517       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        518     finally:
        519       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py in add(self, layer)
        221       # If the model is being built continuously on top of an input layer:
        222       # refresh its output.
    --> 223       output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
        224       if len(nest.flatten(output_tensor)) != 1:
        225         raise ValueError(SINGLE_LAYER_OUTPUT_ERROR_MSG)
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py in __call__(self, inputs, initial_state, constants, **kwargs)
        658 
        659     if initial_state is None and constants is None:
    --> 660       return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
        661 
        662     # If any of `initial_state` or `constants` are specified and are Keras
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        944     # >> model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
        945     if _in_functional_construction_mode(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list):
    --> 946       return self._functional_construction_call(inputs, args, kwargs,
        947                                                 input_list)
        948 
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _functional_construction_call(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list)
       1083           layer=self, inputs=inputs, build_graph=True, training=training_value):
       1084         # Check input assumptions set after layer building, e.g. input shape.
    -> 1085         outputs = self._keras_tensor_symbolic_call(
       1086             inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
       1087 
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call(self, inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
        815       return nest.map_structure(keras_tensor.KerasTensor, output_signature)
        816     else:
    --> 817       return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
        818 
        819   def _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks):
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
        856           # TODO(kaftan): do we maybe_build here, or have we already done it?
        857           self._maybe_build(inputs)
    --> 858           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
        859 
        860         self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent_v2.py in call(self, inputs, mask, training, initial_state)
       1161     # LSTM does not support constants. Ignore it during process.
       1162     orig_initial_state = initial_state
    -> 1163     inputs, initial_state, _ = self._process_inputs(inputs, initial_state, None)
       1164 
       1165     if isinstance(mask, list):
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py in _process_inputs(self, inputs, initial_state, constants)
        857         initial_state = self.states
        858     elif initial_state is None:
    --> 859       initial_state = self.get_initial_state(inputs)
        860 
        861     if len(initial_state) != len(self.states):
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py in get_initial_state(self, inputs)
        640     dtype = inputs.dtype
        641     if get_initial_state_fn:
    --> 642       init_state = get_initial_state_fn(
        643           inputs=None, batch_size=batch_size, dtype=dtype)
        644     else:
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py in get_initial_state(self, inputs, batch_size, dtype)
       2504 
       2505   def get_initial_state(self, inputs=None, batch_size=None, dtype=None):
    -> 2506     return list(_generate_zero_filled_state_for_cell(
       2507         self, inputs, batch_size, dtype))
       2508 
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py in _generate_zero_filled_state_for_cell(cell, inputs, batch_size, dtype)
       2985     batch_size = array_ops.shape(inputs)[0]
       2986     dtype = inputs.dtype
    -> 2987   return _generate_zero_filled_state(batch_size, cell.state_size, dtype)
       2988 
       2989 
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py in _generate_zero_filled_state(batch_size_tensor, state_size, dtype)
       3001 
       3002   if nest.is_nested(state_size):
    -> 3003     return nest.map_structure(create_zeros, state_size)
       3004   else:
       3005     return create_zeros(state_size)
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in map_structure(func, *structure, **kwargs)
        657 
        658   return pack_sequence_as(
    --> 659       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
        660       expand_composites=expand_composites)
        661 
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in <listcomp>(.0)
        657 
        658   return pack_sequence_as(
    --> 659       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
        660       expand_composites=expand_composites)
        661 
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py in create_zeros(unnested_state_size)
       2998     flat_dims = tensor_shape.TensorShape(unnested_state_size).as_list()
       2999     init_state_size = [batch_size_tensor] + flat_dims
    -> 3000     return array_ops.zeros(init_state_size, dtype=dtype)
       3001 
       3002   if nest.is_nested(state_size):
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
        199     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
        200     try:
    --> 201       return target(*args, **kwargs)
        202     except (TypeError, ValueError):
        203       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
       2817 
       2818   def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
    -> 2819     tensor = fun(*args, **kwargs)
       2820     tensor._is_zeros_tensor = True
       2821     return tensor
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in zeros(shape, dtype, name)
       2866           # Create a constant if it won't be very big. Otherwise create a fill
       2867           # op to prevent serialized GraphDefs from becoming too large.
    -> 2868           output = _constant_if_small(zero, shape, dtype, name)
       2869           if output is not None:
       2870             return output
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in _constant_if_small(value, shape, dtype, name)
       2802 def _constant_if_small(value, shape, dtype, name):
       2803   try:
    -> 2804     if np.prod(shape) < 1000:
       2805       return constant(value, shape=shape, dtype=dtype, name=name)
       2806   except TypeError:
    <__array_function__ internals> in prod(*args, **kwargs)
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in prod(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)
       3028     10
       3029     """
    -> 3030     return _wrapreduction(a, np.multiply, 'prod', axis, dtype, out,
       3031                           keepdims=keepdims, initial=initial, where=where)
       3032 
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in _wrapreduction(obj, ufunc, method, axis, dtype, out, **kwargs)
         85                 return reduction(axis=axis, out=out, **passkwargs)
         86 
    ---> 87     return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
         88 
         89 
    ~/miniforge3/envs/tf2.4/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in __array__(self)
        850 
        851   def __array__(self):
    --> 852     raise NotImplementedError(
        853         "Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor ({}) to a numpy array."
        854         " This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to"
    NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (lstm_1/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported
```

Comment: Can you try with latest release i.e `0.1-alpha3` and let us know ? for more details you can refer [this](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos) and [this](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/170). Thanks!

Comment: Yes I did use the version you mentioned

Comment: Had the same issue on m1 macbook.  Confirming that using latest 0.1-alpha3 fixed this issue.